# How to count how many positions away an element is in a list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, max, counting

If I have a list of integers and I want to return the number of spaces away the maximum number is from the beginning of the list, how would I do that if given a list, list1? I should be able to return the integer '7' because 512 is the maximum and it is 7 spaces away.

```
list1=[34,5,1,7,5,3,8,512,8,43]
```

Comment: What if your list has more than one item which is the max, e.g. `list1=[34,5,1,7,5,3,8,512,8,43,512]`? Are you still satisfied with `7` as answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the builtin functions [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) and [`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

```
>>> list1=[34,5,1,7,5,3,8,512,8,43]
>>> max_ele = max(list1)
>>> print(list1.index(max_ele))
7
```

This can be done in a single line as

```
print(list1.index(max(list1)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way:

```
list1.index(max(list1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use enumerate, which will avoid iterating over the list twice:

```
>>> index, element = max(enumerate(list1), key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> index
7
>>> element
512
```

Comment: @TomZych Not actually a hack

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the [solution by @AChampion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33587777/1219006) which avoids iterating the list twice

```
>>> list1=[34,5,1,7,5,3,8,512,8,43]
>>> index, element = max(enumerate(list1), key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> index
7
```

---

Another way to do it efficiently also without iterating the list twice would be as follows:

Python 2:

```
>>> list1=[34,5,1,7,5,3,8,512,8,43]
>>> max(xrange(len(list1)), key=list1.__getitem__)
7
```

On Python 3:

```
>>> list1=[34,5,1,7,5,3,8,512,8,43]
>>> max(range(len(list1)), key=list1.__getitem__)
7
```